Question about the proof that composite numbers are Euler pseudoprimes to at most half of their coprime bases
Euler pseudoprimes are composite numbers $n$ for which the congruence $$a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv \left(\frac{a}{n} \right) \quad (mod \ n)$$ holds, where $\left(\frac{a}{n} \right)$ is the Jacobi symbol. 
There is a theorem that says that for any composite number, this congruence only holds for at most half of the prime residue classes $a\ mod\ n$.
I'm currently working through a proof of that but having some struggle because of a small detail:

The book I have is in German but it basically says that this theorem is true if $U$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, so $U \ne G$. It says that this is the case because then $G$ has at least twice the number of elements as $U$, thus obviously proving the theorem.
I just don't quite get the step from "it is a proper subgroup" to "it has at most half the elements".

The picture is unreadable.  Regardless of that, If $H$ is a proper subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the index of $H$ in $G$ is some natural number greater than $1$, hence the index is at least $2$.

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Due to Lagrange's Theorem, the order of the subgroup $U$ divides the order of $G$. Due to $U \subsetneq G$ we have $|U| < |G|$, so $|G|/|U| > 1$ and hence $|G|/|U| \geq 2$. This implies that $|G| \geq 2 |U|$.
